# How can I split data into multiple workbooks with file name based on column in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, excel-365

I receive a report that contains data in the ranges A:T and about 7000-10000 rows. I need to separate this data into multiple workbooks.

I am aware that you can do it as worksheets. I've come close using this code from https://www.excelhow.net/split-data-into-multiple-worksheets-based-on-column.html. The character limitation of worksheet names causes some issues.

```vb
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer

    'This macro splits data into multiple worksheets based on the variables on a column found in Excel.
    'An InputBox asks you which columns you'd like to filter by, and it just creates these worksheets.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    vcol = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Which column would you like to filter by?", title:="Filter column", Default:="3", Type:=1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
        'Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can I split the data into multiple workbooks based on the Name column (C) or bypass/avoid the worksheet name character limitation, save the worksheets as separate workbooks and rename them later? The files have the name in the title (eg. NameXYZ_report) so preferably the outcome would have it named, based on the column as well.

Summary:

1. Split data into multiple workbooks directly based on Name (Column C value, often exceeds 31 characters) with the file name as ‘Name_report0122’ while keeping header (row 1)
2. Keep column width of original data

If not possible to save directly as workbooks, would it be possible to save as worksheets with a shortened form of the names, save those worksheets as workbooks and then mass rename the files properly afterwards?

Comment: The file names can have more than 31 characters, but the worksheet names cannot exceed this limit. Please clarify how you mean to deal with this. Also, you should post the code you have tried so we can build on that. If you don't have a code, you can use the macro recorder to produce one. You can always [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71098148/edit) with additional details.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, that's actually something I wanted to know as well. I guess if I am able to directly filter and save the data as workbooks then the worksheet limitations won't matter but I was only trying to save them as worksheets since my google searches have shown results for data split -> worksheets -> workbooks. It'd actually be better if I could go straight to workbooks! I've edited my question with code + details, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Export Filtered Data to a New Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 3
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "C:\Test\"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the code. I've tried it in the workbook but it seems to save the new workbooks using the filtered values from column A rather than C (column A only has two types of values eg. A and B so there are only 2 new workbooks named A and B) despite entering column C to be filtered in the prompt. Also, it saves the header row (Row 1) perfectly but no other data is saved. Could you please guide me on which adjustments I should make to have it working?

Comment: Sorry, I made some last-minute changes: you just need to replace `scData = srg.Value` with `scData = scrg.Value` (slip in the `c`). Corrected.

Comment: Thank you! It’s working perfectly so far. I wanted to ask which lines you’d insert or edit to add a common string when the files get named? So it’d be ‘name’ + ‘_reportmmyy’ as an example?

Comment: This line: `dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path`. `Key` is the name so you would do something like `...& Key & DateText & dFileExtension` where `Dim DateText As String: DateText = "_report" & Format(?SomeDate?, "mmyy")`.

Comment: Hi! It’s working perfectly, thank you so much! Have a good day