# Excel VBA Autofilter range fails

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create multiple workbooks from one workbook. Each new workbook contains data from the main workbooks table, filtered by key. I used the code from here:

[Q: How can I split data into multiple workbooks/files based on column in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71098148/q-how-can-i-split-data-into-multiple-workbooks-files-based-on-column-in-excel)

but I had to do some minor adjustments, basically change starting rows / columns. Now, my code fails at the step "srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key" with the error message "AutoFilter method of Range class failed.

This is my code:

```
Sub ExportToWorkbooks()
    
    Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 3
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "C:\Test\"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    ' If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = 2
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A10").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(10) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 11 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        Debug.Print Key
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & dFileExtension ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

My table starts in cell A10.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: `sCol` always has the value of 2, so that _would_ trigger that error if `sws.Range("A10").CurrentRegion` only had 1 column of data. If that isn't the issue then you need to examine the value of `Key` when the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There are actually 30 columns of data and the key is the value that should be used to filter the table - which is the first unique value from column 2.

Comment: Then I suggest you do a test of recording a macro where you AutoFilter, specify the 2nd column and the correct criterion, and then compare what was recorded against the value stored in `Key`

Answer (score 0):

It might not help you after all, but what you can do without need to figure this code out is simply delete top rows from new Workbooks, assuming the data is blank at top 9 rows because of your A10 start table.