# Follow up to splitting a sheet into multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, split

I am trying to modify this code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71098148/q-how-can-i-split-data-into-multiple-workbooks-files-based-on-column-in-excel).

The code works great, but want to know how to enter column letter instead of number.
I believe it has something to do with this line

```
sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
```

but not able to get it to work.

Here is the code as found on the other page.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToWorkbooks()

     Const aibPrompt As String = "Which column would you like to filter by?"
    Const aibtitle As String = "Filter Column"
    Const aibDefault As Long = 3
    
    Dim dFileExtension As String: dFileExtension = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = "C:\Users\WalteR01\Desktop\VPN Revalidations\Split by Manager\"
    
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' folder not found
    If Left(dFileExtension, 1) <> "." Then dFileExtension = "." & dFileExtension
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim sCol As Variant
    sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
    If Len(CStr(sCol)) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no entry
    If sCol = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ActiveSheet
    If sws.FilterMode Then sws.ShowAllData
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If srCount < 3 Then Exit Sub ' not enough rows
    Dim srrg As Range: Set srrg = srg.Rows(1) ' to copy column widths
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = srg.Columns(sCol)
    Dim scData As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Write the unique values from the 1st column to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' case insensitive
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To srCount
        Key = scData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude error values
            If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                dict(Key) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values and blanks
    Erase scData
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfcell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim DateText As String: DateText = Format(Date, "_mm_yyyy")
    
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        ' Add a new (destination) workbook and reference the first cell.
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfcell = dws.Range("A1")
        ' Copy/Paste
        srrg.Copy
        dfcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key
        srg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dfcell
        sws.ShowAllData
        dfcell.Select
        ' Save/Close
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & Key & DateText & dFileExtension  ' build the file path
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next Key
    
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data exported.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

I have tried to change the line as stated but no luck. The application inbox is what I need to update but not sure how. This is the page I have been using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```vb
Dim sCol As Variant
sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 1)
```

As documented here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox#:~:text=The%20following%20table%20lists%20the%20values%20that%20can%20be%20passed%20in%20the%20Type%20argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox#:%7E:text=The%20following%20table%20lists%20the%20values%20that%20can%20be%20passed%20in%20the%20Type%20argument)
The last argument controls what type of value(s) can be accepted by the InputBox: 1 = Numeric so you need to swap that out for 2 (Text)

```vb
sCol = Application.InputBox(aibPrompt, aibtitle, aibDefault, , , , , 2)
```

OK now I read down...  When you call `srg.AutoFilter sCol, Key` the first argument to AutoFilter should be the column number *in the range to be filtered* to which the filter should be applied.
Note if your table doesn't start in ColA there needs to be some adjustment, but if it does you could use `Cells(1, sCol).Column` to convert your column letter, so try:

```vb
srg.AutoFilter sws.Cells(1, sCol).Column, Key
```

Comment: I tried that and it give me a runtime error 1004, "Auto Filter method of Range class failed"